# Express: logical or in routing

Tags: node.js, regex, express

How can I specify a regular expression with OR conditions in Express (v4.15) routing?

I want the following routes to point to the same method

```
/video/:videoId
/movies/:videoId
/media/:videoId
```

When I tried

```
app.get('/(video|media|movies)/:videoId', this.redirectToVideo.bind(this));
```

I got the following error

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\/(?(?:([^\/]+?))|media|movies)\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/?$/: Invalid group
```

When I tried without the ()

```
app.get('/video|media|movies/:videoId', this.redirectToVideo.bind(this));
```

the first 2 routes work, but not that one

```
 /media/:videoId
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to escape the slash `/` with a backslash as `\/`. Use this: `\/(video|media|movies)\/:videoId`

Comment: Also, the error you're getting seems to be for a different regex? `^\/(?(?:([^\/]+?))|media|movies)\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/?$`. The first non-capture group is missing `:` after the question mark `(?:...)` If it's meant to be a capture group, then remove the question mark `?` as `(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a dummy param should work:

```
app.get('/:prefix(video|media|movies)/:videoId', ...);
```

The process used to generate a RegExp from a route path is a little unpredictable.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use an array for your routes:

```
app.get(['/video/:videoId', '/movies/:videoId', '/media/:videoId'], this.redirectToVideo.bind(this))
```

Edit:

If you want to use Regex, this will work also:

```
app.get('(\/video|\/media|\/movies)/:videoId', this.redirectToVideo.bind(this)))
```

Comment: Thanks. I I think I'll use skirtle's answer, as it avoids repetition and I find it clearer to read for complex routes. +1